# Castle Windsor Service binding assemblies

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, assemblies, castle-windsor

Warning: I'm really new to Windsor.

I have 1 solution that has multiple projects.  I have a project that contains all our interfaces (named "Framework") and other ones that hold concrete implementations to those interfaces.  I'm attempting to have Windsor bind these and resolve my interfaces like so:

One of the  other projects is called "Orders" which has an `Order` class that implements `IOrder` which is defined in the frameworks project.  There is a reference between the two projects and it does compile.

I have another project that has the actual windsor call that I've created a installer for:

```
public class CoreInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
  {
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(
          AllTypes.FromAssemblyNamed("Framework"),
          AllTypes.FromAssemblyNamed("Orders")
        );
    }
  }
```

I instantiate the windsor container as such:

```
new WindsorContainer().Install(new CoreInstaller());
```

When I attempt to resolve `IOrder`, it fails with:

> Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentNotFoundException: No component for supporting the service Framework.IOrder was found

I've also tried flipping the projects in the install function to load `Orders` first but I get the same error.

Any Windsor users out there that can help me?

Comment: FYI, "Classes" is funtionally equivalent to "AllTypes", but it's clearer what is done.  [More Info](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Whats-New-In-Windsor-3.ashx#Added_Classes_and_Types_registration_API_entry_types_for_batch_registration_of_components_12)

Comment: Be careful with this usage. You are registering all types as singletons (the default lifestyle). You may have threading issues.

Answer (score 1):

You have effectively told Windsor to get all the types, but you haven't told it what to do with them yet.  If you are not going to filter the types you want to register and what interface you want to register with, you need to add the Pick() method to your registration.

For example...

```
container.Register(
    Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("Framework").Pick(),
    Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("Orders").Pick()
);
```

Comment: This is nasty. I think @OnResolve's code makes sense and it's a #fail it doesn't work. I'd log it to the issue tracker for someone to implement, or better yet send a pull request ;)

Comment: It's just a design decision and I bet there's a technical reason why a FromAssemblyDescriptor does not register the classes directly.  I agree that it's not obvious and could have been named better in a Fluent API like this, but I'm sure they had their reasons.